# Web site does not open without www

Tags: bind

My website will not open without writing ***www*** in the URL.

Hosting and DNS servers are in the same machine.

I tried to search, no result.
I tried to put dot after test.com in the last line, did not help.

Here is my bind configuration.
How can I resolve this?
Thank you.

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.test.com. admin.test.com. (
                 15     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
;@  IN  NS  localhost.
;@  IN  A   127.0.0.1
;@  IN  AAAA    ::1

    IN  NS  ns1.test.com.

ns1.test.com.   IN  A   11.22.33.44
mail.test.com.  IN  A   11.22.33.45

test.com.       IN  MX  8   mail.test.com.

www.test.com.   IN  CNAME   ns1.test.com.
test.com        IN  CNAME   ns1.test.com.
```

Comment: You should indicate what is the symptom : does the Web server reply (something you don’t want like a 404 error), or the browser gives you an error. The DNS configuration looks fine.

Comment: I'm a little old, but don't you use `iptables` to forward your port 80?

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer, just does not load the page, DNS error. But if I add www, then it loads.

Comment: @Philippos, there is a redirection in web server configuration. The problem is not in redirecting, problem: wont open without www.

Comment: Could you try https://www.nslookup.io/ with your domain ? Perhaps their is a cache issue. You also have the `nslookup` command on your PC. If both interrogations gives you different results, it should be a cache issue.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer, it resolves www.test.com, but it cannot resolve test.com

Comment: hm, your nameserver being the authorative instance to resolve its own address – that's a fragile thing. Also, my DNS is getting a bit rusty, but your zone seems to be `ns1.test.com`, but you have things outside that zone in your zone file

Answer (score 0):

The last line is illegal. [You can’t have a CNAME record on the root of a DNS zone.](https://www.nslookup.io/learning/dns-record-types/cname/)

Instead, a common pattern is to CNAME www to the root of the zone, and have the root resolve with A/AAAA.

Comment: I have deleted last line. But still not able to enter site without writing www in URL.

Comment: In your case you'd need something like
`test.com.   IN  A   11.22.33.44` and 
`www.test.com.   IN  CNAME   test.com.`